# Finding the largest combination given a list/array of integers

Tags: java, sorting

A problem given by my lab professor, as the title reads:
*Find the largest combination given a list/array of integers.*
ie:

```
input: {10, 68, 75, 7, 21, 12}
stdout: 77568211210
my output : 75768211210
```

The current code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class classwork6
{
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static void sort(String[] arr)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[j])<0)
                {
                    String temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] list = {10, 68, 75, 7, 21, 12};
        String[] arr = new String[list.length];
        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = String.valueOf(list[i]);
        }
        sort(arr);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[\\[\\], ]",""));
    }
}
```

My first attempt was simply sorting the array, after which I quickly found out that 777568211210>75682112107

My latest attempt was to lexicographically compare the string values of the integers. Yet the output is still incorrect
777568211210>75768211210

Comment: Can you be more precise? Explain how that combination works? Is What kind of operations is it or is it just joining values together like 12 + 22 = 1222?

Comment: Do you understand that the solution is NOT to sort the array ? `["19", "9"]` is maximized with 919 not 199

Comment: I'm currently just concatenating string values of the integers together :>

Comment: I have minimal experience in programming, my initial thought was to sort because I did not think about those cases.

Comment: A reverse _lexical sorting_ (by character/strings) of your array would just about work, you'd need to simply weight by their combination instead of individually (since `"75" > "7"` for reverse lexical). Thus: `{10, 68, 75, 7, 21, 12} => {7, 75, 68, 21, 12, 10}`, which concatenates to `77568211210`.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. But think about it, which number will "give" more to the final result: 91 or 911.

It should be obvious that the shorter number gives more "possibilities" to get higher number. So your sort should prioritize shorter numbers if two numbers begin with same characters

Comment: So, applying my sorts in the order of ascending number of digits and descending values?

Comment: Well, something like that. But beware that number "1" would not be "more" than example "21", so you still need to compare the characters one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Just `lexically` compare each pair of integers as strings, concatenated back to back.  Consider `77` and `234`. `"77243"` is `lexically` greater than `"23477"`. So `77` would come first, then `234`.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(92, 101, 79, 42, 2002, 22));

Comparator<Integer> comp = (b,a)-> (a+""+b).compareTo(b+""+a);

list.sort(comp);
System.out.println(list);
    
String result = list.stream().map(i->Integer.toString(i)).reduce("",String::concat);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
[92, 79, 42, 22, 2002, 101]
927942222002101
```